# How to copy a folder, subfolders and its files into a library on another site

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I'm not sure sure how to go about this, but I would like some help to create a flow that will copy a selected folder, its subfolders and files into another library on a different site.

i currently have this [image: Example flow]

This flow copies the folder and subfolders fine, just not the files that are within the folders.

Any ideas on what I need to do so the files get copied over too?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, the action '[Copy folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/connectors/sharepointonline/#copy-folder)' will copy the inside files as well. But the files should at least have a "check-in" version, all files without a checked-in version will not be copied.